# Is there a way to separate the project working directory from the start-up directory in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm struggling to separate project working directory and start-up directory for Jupyter notebook

It seems like wherever I create/open a notebook same directory would be the working directory (pwd), but my will is to have it different without using os.chdir
Does anyone have suggestions how it could be achieved in Jupyter_notebook_config.py?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `os.chdir()`?

Comment: Looking for ways of optimising my workflow, I really don't want every notebook start with this extra two lines as well as getting copy-paste full path of project folder

Comment: Have you tried putting the `os.chdir()` inside `Jupyter_notebook_config.py`, or setting `NotebookApp.notebook_dir`( https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html#options ) or pairing the start-up command with an os-level change-directory, e.g. `cd ~/my_notebook_dir && /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/jupyter`. (I dunno your OS or directory structure, so am guessing at the dirs there...). Any of those seem like they *might* work, but trying them and discussing why you dislike the results could help - or give you a self-answer.

Comment: Mac OS, notebook version 6.5.3
NotebookApp.notebook_dir is same as start-up folder.  so if c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = '/Users/user/proejct/notebooks/somedirectory'; pwd would be same and project files is two levels above without possibility to import modules correct

Comment: putting the os.chdir() inside config would just set wd for current script, no?)